# Set default value when form loads

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, codeigniter

```
   <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records2, '#', 'id="items"'); ?>
```

I want to set the default value of something in the select box whenever the form loads. 
If it is not possible, then I would like to convert this into regular select box. 
Will something like this work?

```
<select name="select1" id="items" class='cho'>
<option>--Select--  </option>
    <?php foreach($records2 as $r) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$r->item_id?>">
<?=$r->item_name?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I tried this, but I am getting an error and values not come up into the select box.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *exactly* is in `$records3`?

Comment: the values which are coming from controller

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected. You can also pass an array of multiple items through the third parameter

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('select1', $records2, $selected_value);  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how this helper function works:

```
form_dropdown('item_id',    $records3,    '#',           'id="items"')
//             field name   options       default value   HTML attributes
```

Options *must* be an array in key/value format*, for example:

```
$options = array(
    'value1' => 'Text 1',
    'value2' => 'Text 2',
    'value3' => 'Text 3'
);
```

The default value should be one of the keys in `$options`, or nothing will happen.

It looks like you'll need to create this array first rather than just pass in `$records2`:

```
$options = array();
foreach ($records2 as $r) {
    $options[$r->item_id] = $r->item_name;
}
echo form_dropdown('item_id', $options, '{default value}', 'id="items"');
```

<sub>* If the array passed as $options is a multidimensional array, form_dropdown() will produce an `<optgroup>` with the array key as the label.</sub>

Comment: but i am getting the values from database ..how can i do it ?

Comment: so what is the third parameter doing ... i write watever there .. nothing happens

Comment: I've already explained that and I'm not sure how to make it any clearer, try reading slower. What do you *want* to happen? Maybe take 10 minutes and read the docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: If you set the default value as `#`, the option with `value="#"` will be selected by default. If it doesn't exist, it won't do anything.

Comment: wait this was my comment before your answer updation

Comment: I had explained that before the update. Does it make sense now?

Comment: i have copied your code and paste it .. now i am getting the error            Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object                                   ok just tell me how to i convert this line to regular select box ...<?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records2, '#', 'id="items"'); ?>     because this line works .. and if i am able to done this into regular select then this default value thing will not happen ..

Comment: I think your best bet is to achieve an understanding of the errors you're having. Without a firm grasp on the basics of PHP, it will be difficult to proceed. Sorry, but I cannot help you further.